# Java Installation in Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: software-installation, java, environment-variables

This is my first time of using Ubuntu. I am trying to install java jdk-15 in my lap.I applied following steps.

1. sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15/bin/java 1
2. sudo update-alternatives --config java
3. sudo gedit /etc/environment => I saved the path (JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15" )
4. source /etc/environment ==> this step outputs "JAVA_HOME: command not found"

Why do I get this? Pls help me.

Comment: Maybe because there are spaces before and after the `=` character.

Answer (score 0):

## Check your JDK install

First, ensure your desired JDK version is indeed installed:
`javac -version` should output some information.
To get an overview of the different JDK versions installed on your computer, you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`. This command should display at least the JDK version you target.

## Install JDK if needed

If no Java is installed, or if you don't have the version you wish, you will have to install it.

#### From Ubuntu repositories (easiest, best secured and supported)

openjdk-15 is available in Ubuntu repository for Groovy. Here are the different openjdk versions available per Ubuntu version :
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=openjdk-&searchon=names

Once you've made your version choice, install it with `sudo apt install open-jdk-VERSION-jdk`.

#### From third party providers (more options available but more steps required)

If you really want openjdk-15 but run in another version than Groovy, you'll have two options:

- take JDK 15 from Openjdk website and install it manually : https://openjdk.java.net/install/. You will have to download a tar.gz file, decompress it, and then move it into a folder that is part of your PATH. I would not recommend this option as it will require you to perform future JDK update manually.
- there is also a nice alternative that consists in using AdoptOpenJDK PPA:
  https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html?variant=openjdk15&jvmVariant=hotspot#linux-pkg. If you go for it, you'll install JDK 15 with `sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-15-hotspot`. I would definitely recommend this option as it is easier to setup and you'll get updates when running `sudo apt upgrade`.

Once Java is installed, run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` to use this version by default, and check that `javac -version` now gives you the right version.

## Define JAVA_HOME

In the /etc/environment file, you can follow this syntax (adapting it to your effective path):
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-15-hotspot-amd64/bin/java`
Notice that there's no space around "=" sign and the path can be unquoted.

Once done, use `source /etc/environment` or reboot your computer to take the change into account.

Now, if you enter `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it should display the path to your Java executable.